# Fragment caching for each session id separetely, Rails 4 + Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, caching

I want to cache search block for each user/visitor separately so when user/visitor **has searched or sorted for anything** search block is cached with all CSS and visual changes. So when user revisits Advertisement#index page in 5.minutes Rails cache renders the same search block  as he left.

Previously, I tried to count clicks on sort links and then save them as cookies and then when Advertisement#index page is loaded, make all clicks. But that approach was very nasty and didn't work sometimes.

Search block:
[image]

**So far** I have successfully cached search results and retrieving them based on session.id.

**My code in Advertisement_controller:index** :

```
  if params[:q].present?  #if search params is present 
         @cache_search = true  #this is for fragment cache in view
         Rails.cache.delete("q_#{request.session.id}")
         Rails.cache.write("q_#{request.session.id}",params[:q],:expires_in => 5.minutes)       
         @search = @adver.search(params[:q]) 

     else
          params[:q] = Rails.cache.read("q_#{request.session.id}")
          @search = @adver.search(params[:q])       
     end


      @search.sorts = ['height asc','age asc','votes_for.size asc'] if @search.sorts.empty?  
      @advertisements = @search.result(distinct: true) 

      #delete cache is search resulted in 0 results
      if @advertisements.present?
      else

         Rails.cache.delete("q_#{request.session.id}")
      end
```

This code generates this cache: q_925feaae9c1cd1f6948899e672838c0a.

**My search block:**

```
<% cache_if @cache_search == true, request.session.id do %>
    <%= search_form_for @search, :class=>"search",:id=>"search-menio",:remote=>"true", url: girls_path, :method => :get do |f| %>

          <%= f.text_field :name_or_phone_number_or_identifier_cont, :id=>"search-field-keyup",:class=>"form-control-s" %>
          <%end%>

          <%= sort_link(@search, :height,t('height'),{hide_indicator: true},{ :remote => true, :method => :get }) %>  
          <%= sort_link(@search, :age,t('age'),{hide_indicator: true},{ :remote => true, :method => :get }) %>  
          <%= sort_link(@search, 'votes_for.size',t('rating'), {hide_indicator: true},{ :remote => true, :method => :get }) %>  


   <%end%>
<%end%>
```

**Problem**: Rails wont cache search block when search occurs, but when I first time visit Advertisement#index page. How could edit my code so search block cache is renewed each time search occurs and serve this cached search block for 5.minutes or new search ?

I have searched for similair questions, but none was like mine.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer may be too late for your purposes, but I'll answer for future searchers.  A couple of ideas:

- I think the reason your view is caching the main index page instead of the search, is because the cache key depends only on the session id.  Subsequent visits to the same page with new search parameters do not generate a cache miss since the session id has not changed.  You can solve this by adding the search parameters to the cache key: `[@search, request.session.id]`.  You may also want to expire the fragment cache in five minutes.
- As an additional recommendation, I suggest storing your query string, `params[:q]`, in the session instead of in the cache.  That way it is certain to be there for five minutes.  A cache item could expire early if the cache fills up. You would need to add a timestamp to the session so you can expire the query string after 5 minutes.

I would recommend coding this up as follows:

**controller**

```
def index
    if params[:q].present?  #if search params is present 
        @cache_search = true  #this is for fragment cache in view
        session[:search_string] = params[:q]
        session[:q_created_at] = Time.now.to_i
    elsif session[:q_created_at].present? && session[:q_created_at] > 5.minutes.ago.to_i
        params[:q] = session[:q]
    end

    @search = @adver.search(params[:q]) if params[:q].present?
    @search.sorts = ['height asc','age asc','votes_for.size asc'] if @search.sorts.empty?
    @advertisements = @search.result(distinct: true) 

    #delete query string session parameters if search resulted in 0 results
    unless @advertisements.present?
        session.delete(:q)
        session.delete(:q_created_at)
    end
end
```

**view**

```
<% cache_if @cache_search, [@search, request.session.id] do %>
    <%= search_form_for @search, :class=>"search",:id=>"search-menio",:remote=>"true", url: girls_path, :method => :get do |f| %>

          <%= f.text_field :name_or_phone_number_or_identifier_cont, :id=>"search-field-keyup",:class=>"form-control-s" %>
          <%end%>

          <%= sort_link(@search, :height,t('height'),{hide_indicator: true},{ :remote => true, :method => :get }) %>  
          <%= sort_link(@search, :age,t('age'),{hide_indicator: true},{ :remote => true, :method => :get }) %>  
          <%= sort_link(@search, 'votes_for.size',t('rating'), {hide_indicator: true},{ :remote => true, :method => :get }) %>  


   <%end%>
<%end%>
```

This code has not been tested.